# Has cryonics been treated in Rabbinic literature?

Tags: death, technology, science, modern-times, afterlife

Has it been treated by rabbinic literature? If yes, what does it say about cryonics?

Comment: While the answer http://www.cryonet.org/cgi-bin/dsp.cgi?msg=13925 deals with it the specific question aboit "rabbinical literature" is not fully dealt with